# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method on model method that references itself using many to many relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm building a system where a user can have many teachers (Same User model) and teachers can have many users. When I hit the controller I get:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/User::teachers()

### Code

**Controller**

```
public function requestTeacher()
{
    $teacher = User::where(['hashed_id' => 'auserhash123', 'is_teacher' => 1])->first();

    $user = auth()->user()->first();

    $teacher->notify(new teacherRequest($user));

    $user->teachers()->attach($teacher->id);
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','teacher_approval','user_id','teacher_id');
}

public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','teacher_approval','teacher_id','user_id');
}
```

**teacher_approval table**

```
Schema::create('teacher_approval', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('teacher_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('status')->default(0);
    $table->timestamp('decission_date')->nullable();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Edit:**

I wonder if this is because the User is extending SparkUser (I'm using laravel Spark) `class User extends SparkUser { }`